# Receive answer from WCF-service's boolean method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, service

my problem is:

I have WCF service, which contains one method, that can return true of false.
I call this method by JS on client.

My problem is to call this method, then to wait it's answer and then, for example, alert if true.

My SVC file:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "AttributeSetAttributeService")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public Boolean SaveChanges(string aaa, string bbb, string ccc)
        {
            // code here
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I calling this function on client by JS:

```
if (WayToMyServiceMethod.SaveChanges(aaa, bbb, ccc) == false) {
        alert("false");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("true");
        return true;
    }
```

But it always alerts 'true' and parallel executes service method (SaveChanges) without waiting for answer from service.

I need to WAIT answer from service and when it completes get 'true' or 'false'.

Sorry for my english :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your server method SaveChanges it always returns true . So you gets true always. If your server implementation is correctly returning true or false try the below checking in client side

In javscript you should check using '===' for type checking too.

```
if (WayToMyServiceMethod.SaveChanges(aaa, bbb, ccc) === false) {
        alert("false");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("true");
        return true;
    }
```